# Python : Receiving empty list from another file on importing

Tags: python

I have a data loader file(data.py) that loads my `courses` list with data. It works fine as courses list does get loaded with my JSON data.

data.py is :-

```py
import json
import os
courses = []

def load_data():
    """Load the data from the json file.
    """
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = 'json\course.json'
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
    with open(abs_file_path) as json_file:
        courses = json.load(json_file)
        print(courses)
```

When I try to import the `courses` list in another python file, I am receiving it as an empty list. I am importing it as

```py
import data
print(data.courses)
```

Comment: You defined it as an empty list.  You don't change it anywhere in your posted code.  Why are you confused that the import gives you the empty list?

Comment: @Prune He assumed it would call `load_data` automatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `import data`, you are executing the file again, but you are not running the function. So to solve it, you need to run `load_data()` in your current file so that it populates the courses list.
Your new code should look like this:

```
import data
data.load_data()
print(data.courses)
```

However, what you're doing is wrong. You don't define the data in your data.py. What if multiple files imported data? Instead you need to just return the loaded data. So the function becomes:

```
def load_data():
    """Load the data from the json file.
    """
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = 'json\course.json'
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
    with open(abs_file_path) as json_file:
        return json.load(json_file)
```

That should also be your entire `data.py` along with the imports. Now you can just `from data import load_data` and call `load_data()` whenever you want. I suggest having `file_name` as a parameter so that you can choose where to load from each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer,  but won't this be bad practice if the data I need to load is very big?

Comment: @YashBoura it depends on what you want to do. If you have enough memory then go ahead. If you don't, then convert load_data() into a generator and instead of `print(courses)` you need to `yield` a single course. But since it's already `json` I don't think you can do much about it.

Answer (score 3):

You need actually load the data first so

**Import.py**

```
import data
print(data.load_data())
```

**Data.py**

```
import json
import os
courses = []

def load_data():
    """Load the data from the json file.
    """
    script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
    rel_path = 'json\course.json'
    abs_file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, rel_path)
    with open(abs_file_path) as json_file:
        courses = json.load(json_file)
    return courses
```